# Proof of analogue of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to vector

Tags: inequality, vectors

[Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) can be writen:
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot y_i\right|^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2,\qquad \forall  x_i,y_i \in \Bbb R
$$

My question is, if $x_i,y_i \in \Bbb R^m$, do the above inequation still hold up?

More generally, if there some inequality like above hold for $\Bbb R$, can it be always  generalized to $\Bbb R^n$?

P.S.: $x_i\cdot y_i$ means dot product

Comment: The CS inequality is applicable for $n$ vectors, but not in the way you write.  what does $x_i y_i $ mean when $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb R^m$?

Comment: This makes no sense, you should view $x=(x_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not the components $x_i$. Macavity also makes clear that this makes no sense.

Comment: $x_iy_i$ means dot product

Comment: @Mathematician42 It could make sense. For $n=2$, take vectors $u,v,w,x$. What it seems to ask is whether $(u\cdot v + w\cdot x)^2\le(u\cdot u+w\cdot w)(v\cdot v + x\cdot x)$ is true or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is true in any inner-product space. There are many examples of these. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Examples) for a few of them.

You can carry out the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in an arbitrary abstract inner product space. It's not very different from the ones you may have seen for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. There are two proofs on the Wikipedia page cited above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The inequality is equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $R^{ n m}$.

Let $N=\{1,...,n\}$ and $M=\{1,...,m\}.$ Let $f$ be the   bijection $f:N\times M\to \{1,..., n m\}$ such that $f(i,j)<f(i',j')\iff [i<i'\lor (i=i'\land j<j')].$

For $x_i=(x_{i,j})_{1\leq j\leq m} \in R^m$ and $y_i=(y_{i,j})_{1\leq j\leq m}\in R^m,$ let $x_{i,j}=x^*_{f(i,j)}$ and $y_{i,j}=y^*_{f(i,j)}.$ Then $x=(x^*_s)_{1\leq s\leq n m }\in R^{n m}$ and $y=(y^*_s)_{1\leq s\leq n m}\in R^{n m}.$  The inequality is, verbatim, $(x\cdot y)^2 \leq \|x\|^2\cdot \|y\|^2.$